# Is there any way to map the <img > to every object in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, html-table

I want to map questions array to table rows. While setting the preview for uploaded image in any row, it always gets rendered in first .Ideally, for each object in question array, once a file is input it's preview will be shown in next  in an img tag. Can you please tell how to correct it?

[image]

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]); // it will contain an array of objects
  // like [{quesID, ques, options, media}, {quesID, ques, options, media} ]

<table aria-label="simple table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <td>Question</td>
  <td>Options</td>
  <td align="center">
    Grade
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Level
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Subject
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Topic 1
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Topic 2
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Topic 3
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Upload image
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    Preview image
  </td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{questions.map((row) => (
  <tr key={row.id}>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      component="th"
      scope="row"
    >
      <TextField
        margin="dense"
        id="editQues"
        variant="filled"
        multiline
        sx={{
          width: 300,
          color: "success.main",
        }}
        maxRows={4}
        defaultValue={row.ques}
        onChange={(e) => {
          row.ques = e.target.value;
          console.log(row.ques);
          console.log(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      component="th"
      scope="row"
    >
      <TextField
        margin="dense"
        id="editOpt"
        variant="filled"
        multiline
        sx={{
          width: 200,
          color: "success.main",
        }}
        maxRows={4}
        defaultValue={row.options.join(", ")}
        onChange={(e) => {
          row.options = e.target.value.split(", ");
          console.log(row.options);
          console.log(e.target.value);
          console.log("updated questions is", questions);
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
    >
      {row.grade.join(",")}
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
    >
      {row.level}
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
    >
      {row.subject}
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
    >
      {row.topic}
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
    >
      {row.subTopic ? row.subTopic : ""}
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
    >
      {row.subSubTopic ? row.subSubTopic : ""}
    </td>
    <td style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="uploadMedia"
        name="uploadMedia"
        accept="image/*, video/* "
        onChange={(event) => {
          const file = event.target.files[0];
          if (file) {
            row.file = file;
            var output = document.getElementById("blah");
            output.src = URL.createObjectURL(
              event.target.files[0]
            );
            output.onload = function () {
              // URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src); // free memory
            };
          } else {
            row.file = null;
          }
          console.log("media", row.file);
        }}
      />
    </td>
    <td
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      align="center"
      scope="row"
    >
      <img
        id="blah"
        src="#"
        alt="your image"
        width="100"
        height="100"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer the question, but I notice that you're mutating `row` (`row.ques = e.target.value`, `row.file = file` etc), which looks suspicious. You should usually update things using a state setter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Is there any other way to select the img tag of concerned row, as shown in image? Selecting image from any of the inputs for now updates the image only in the first img. 
Like here I'm using var output document.getElementById("blah"); which is always giving the first rows image but it has to map image for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i did understand what you mean , try to use

```
var output = document.querySelector('img');
```

instead of `var output = document.getElementById("blah");`